# Find all possible 3-in-a-row adjacent elements within a 2D triangular grid

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Floyd's triangle is an arrangement of the positive integers into a triangle such that the $n$th line contains $n$ integers. To illustrate, here are the first 4 lines of Floyd's triangle:

```
 1
 2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9 10
```

I am trying to design a function that takes as input an integer `n`, and returns a list of all the ways to select 3 elements from `n` rows of Floyd's triangle such that they lie consecutively in a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal line within the triangle. For example, for an input of `4` (corresponding to the triangle shown above) the expected output would be

```
{{1,2,4}, {1,3,6}, {2,4,7}, {2,5,9}, {3,5,8}, {3,6,10}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {8,9,10}}
```

I have a boring and clunky procedural implementation currently, which I post below as an answer, but I expect there exist pithier solutions that make better use of *Mathematica*'s powers. In particular, I might expect that there would be a solution that does not require me to explicitly generate the triangle.

Answer (score 4):

My current solution is to explicitly construct the triangle as a list of lists, then loop through it to find each horizontal, vertical, and diagonal triple:

```
triples[n_] := With[{triangle = TakeList[Range[Total[#]], #]& @ Range[n]},
  Table[{
    (* horizontal *) triangle[[i+2, j;;j+2]],
    (* vertical *)   triangle[[i;;i+2, j]],
    (* diagonal *)   triangle[[i;;i+2, -j]]
  }, {i, n-2}, {j, i}] ~Flatten~ 2

triples[4]
(* {{4,5,6}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,6}, {7,8,9}, {2,4,7}, {3,6,10}, {8,9,10}, {3,5,8}, {2,5,9}} *)
```

But I am hoping y'all have smarter approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If the triangle is given as

```
tri = {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

and one wants to select `k` consecutive elements, then you can do this:

```
With[{k = 3}, 
     Sort[Flatten[If[Length[#] >= k, Partition[#, k, 1], Nothing] & /@ 
                  Join[tri, Flatten[tri, {{2}, {1}}],
                       Array[Diagonal[tri, 1 - #] &, Length[tri]]], 1]]]
   {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 10}, {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}, {8, 9, 10}}
```